# Problema con el contexto de un Toast

Tags: android, android-studio, android-context, android-toast

El programa me marca error en el contexto del `toast`. Ya probé con `getApplicationContext()`, con `NombreActivity.this` y con solamente `this`.

Tengo una activity principal llamada ReaderActivity, de ella mando llamar a ServiceListener, que es una clase java.

Dentro del ServiceListener está el toast dentro de un OnClick. Acá les dejo el código.[Aquí mando llamar la clase Service Listener[image: ][1]]

Comment: Agrega como texto tu código amigo, en este caso tu clase completa, es más fácil que lo lea la comunidad.

Comment: Esta clase Service Listener esta extendida a AppCompatActivity?, si no no podrias obtener el contexto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu clase extiende de `Activity`, `AppCompatActivity` etc, puedes usar:

`getApplicationContext()`, `NombreActivity.this` o `this`

Si tu clase extiende de `Service` puedes usar:

```
this
```

**Pero en este caso debes enviar el contexto a la clase.** En este caso puedes modificar tu clase `ServiceListener` para que cuando la crees, envíes el contexto desde la `Activity`, ejemplo:

```
ServiceListener servListener = new ServiceListener(getApplicationContext());
```

de esta forma puedes obtener el contexto en la clase listener.

```
private Context context;

 //Puedes recibir en el constructor el contexto.
 public ServiceListener(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;       
  }
```

Ahora la variable `context`  sería la que usarías como contexto.

Comment: Muchas gracias.