# Obtengo: getApplicationContext() on a null object reference cuando uso un Geocoder

Tags: java, android-studio, geolocalización, gps

Estoy haciendo un app donde obtienes tu ubicación usando el GPS y se la mandas a alguien por correo automáticamente, pero sestoy obteniendo un error, ya que hice otra clase de tipo de servicio para que siempre este activa, y cuando uso el código ahí, me da un error que antes no me daba

```
    public void setLocation (Location loc){
    //Obtener la direccion de la calle a partir de la latitud y la longitud
    if (loc.getLatitude() != 0.0 && loc.getLongitude() != 0.0) {
        try {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                    loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
            geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                Address DirCalle = list.get(0);
                mensaje22 = "Mi direccion es: " + DirCalle.getAddressLine(0);
                contenido_correo2 = contenido_correo2 + "\n" + mensaje22;
            }
            if (interruptor_inicio2) {
                timer22.schedule(timertask2, 10000, 60000);
                interruptor_inicio2 = false;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Esa es la funcionó para obtener la dirección
Y este es el LOG:

```
2019-02-25 21:59:25.383 26163-26163/apps.omarf.com.securityapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: apps.omarf.com.securityapp, PID: 26163
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:106)
    at apps.omarf.com.securityapp.BG.setLocation(BG.java:148)
    at apps.omarf.com.securityapp.BG.onLocationChanged(BG.java:81)
    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:297)
    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.-wrap0(LocationManager.java)
    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:242)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

Comment: Tu clase es un Adapter, Fragment, Activity? @OmarFernando

Comment: La verdad soy novato en esto y no si es correcto lo que diga, es que según yo la clase extiende un servicio, y en el manifest está declarada como servicio, entonces supongo que es un servicio, pero no sé si sea correcto

Comment: Ok revisa la actualización de mi respuesta, usa "this" como contexto si te encuentras en un servicio.

Comment: ya lo probe, y me dio: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el contexto de esta forma:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
```

tu clase debe extender de `Activity`

---

Si tu clase no extiende de `Activity`, puedes modificar el método publico `setLocation()` para que reciba el contexto y usarlo al instanciar `Geocoder`:

```
  public void setLocation (Location loc, Context ctx){
     ...
     ...
     Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(ctx, Locale.getDefault());
     ...
     ...
  }
```

---

Actualización:

**Si la clase extiende de `Service` en este caso puedes usar `this` para obtener el contexto.**

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
```

Puedes ver aquí más información acerca de como obtener el contexto:

[Problema con el contexto de un Toast](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/172702/problema-con-el-contexto-de-un-toast/172712#172712)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo intentaré y comento como me fue